# Any epsilon-delta proof of the continuity of the inverse of a real-valued strictly monotonic continuous function on an open interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, inverse-function, monotone-functions

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $a < b$, and let $f \colon (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly monotonic, continuous function. Then I can show that the range of $f$ is also an open interval $(c, d)$, where $-\infty \leq c < d \leq +\infty$. Thus the inverse function $g \colon (c, d) \to (a, b)$ exists and the inverse function $g$ is also strictly monotonic: $g$ is strictly increasing if $f$ is strictly increasing, whereas $g$ is strictly decreasing if $f$ is strictly decreasing. Moreover, $g$ is also continuous on all of (c, d). I can show this through the inverse images of open intervals argument.

Now my question is, how to prove the continuity of $g$ at an arbitrary point $q \in (c, d)$, using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument?

My Attempt:

> Suppose $q \in (c, d)$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then we can find a unique point $p \in (a, b)$ for which $q = f(p)$. As $f$ is continuous at $p$, so we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(p) \rvert < \varepsilon $$
>   for every point $x \in (a, b)$ for which 
>   $$ \lvert x-p \rvert < \delta. $$
>   That is, 
>   $$ f(p) - \varepsilon < f(x) < f(p) + \varepsilon $$
>   whenever $$ a < x < b \ \mbox{ and } \ p-\delta < x < p + \delta. $$
>   The last statement is equivalent to saying that 
>   $$ f(x) \in \big( f(p) - \varepsilon, f(p) + \varepsilon \big) $$
>   whenever $$ x \in (a, b) \cap \big( p - \delta, p + \delta \big). $$

What next? How to proceed from here and show that the function $g$ is continuous at the point $q \in (c, d)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what have you edited in my post?

Comment: I removed the `analysis` tag (it was redundant, since you are already using the `real-analysis` tag) and I have added the `inverse-function` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume without loss of generality that $f$ is increasing. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Again, you can assume without loss of generality that $\varepsilon$ is so small that $(p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon)\subset(a,b)$. Let $\delta>0$ be so small that $(q-\delta,q+\delta)\subset\bigl(f(p-\varepsilon),f(p+\varepsilon)\bigr)$. Then\begin{align}|x-q|<\delta&\implies x\in\bigl(f(p-\varepsilon),f(p+\varepsilon)\bigr)\\&\implies g(x)\in(p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon)\\&\iff\bigl|g(x)-g(q)\bigr|<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: thank you. Your answer is clear enough.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: there is one small point, however, that I'd like to raise. From your proof, it seems that in showing that $g$ is continuous at $q$, we needn't use the continuity of the function $f$ at the point $p$. Is it really so?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Indeed, the continuity of $f$ is not needed.

Comment: but this makes me a bit skeptical, I'm afraid. Does this mean that the inverse of any real-valued function strictly monotonic on an open interval on the real line is continuous, irrespective of whether the function itself is continuous or not?

Comment: I hope that this example will persuade you: let $f\colon[-1,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be defined by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x<0\\&x+1\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$It is discontinuous at $0$. Its inverse is$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&[-1,0)\cup[1,2]&\longrightarrow&[-1,1]\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x<0\\x-1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$It is continuous at $1(=f(0))$, right?!

Comment: I recall seeing a short published note on the fact that a strictly increasing function has a continuous inverse, and I actually have a photocopy of it somewhere, but unfortunately I can't find it now (not surprising) nor can I remember enough about it to find it in my various personal-use bibliographies. Anyway, it was a 2-part note, the other part having to do with an entirely unrelated topic, and I believe it was published in *Mathematical Gazette*, probably 25 to 50 years ago. Oh well . . .